# Baidu map URL with coordinates

Tags: google-maps, maps, baidu, baidu-map

i wanted to open a Baidu map with a URL with co-ordinates (latitude/longitude in some form)

For normal browsers this is working

http://map.baidu.com/?l=13&tn=B_NORMAL_MAP&c=13748138,4889173&s=gibberish

thanks to - https://annoyingtechnicaldetails.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/parsing-baidu-map-urls/

But this is not working for mobile browsers. Can anyone with knowledge of baidu map URLs help with making a map URL with co-ordinates with http://map.baidu.com/mobile ?

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer. For anyone looking in future:

```
http://api.map.baidu.com/marker?location=39.916979519873,116.41004950566&output=html
```